# Remove the "same as the whole table" property from Outlook table

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've got the following code to "Codeize" a block of code in an outlook message:

```
On Error GoTo Catch
Dim oSelection As Word.Selection
Set oSelection = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.GetInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection

With oSelection
    With .Font
        .Name = "Courier New"
        '.Color = 10027008 '13369344
        .Size = 10
    End With
End With

Dim oTable As Word.Table
Set oTable = oSelection.ConvertToTable(, 1, 1)
With oTable
    .Borders.OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleDot
    .Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorGray05
    .TopPadding = InchesToPoints(0.1)
    .BottomPadding = InchesToPoints(0.1)
    .LeftPadding = InchesToPoints(0.2)
    .RightPadding = InchesToPoints(0.05)
End With
```

Works great, BUT I think **I cannot get the margins to work** because I'm missing whatever removes the **"Same as the whole table" property**.

After the code runs, the Table Properties looks like this:

[image]

Perhaps I'm just setting the margins wrong, and this will automatically go away? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Word provides a macro recorder which allows to generate the VBA code in the background. Try to record a VBA macro in Word and see what properties should be used for that. See [Record or run a macro](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Record-or-run-a-macro-cd56fb86-d8b2-475c-ba39-9728389feeeb?ui=en-US&rs=en-CA&ad=CA&fromAR=1) for more information.

Comment: Actually, I tried that. You can't right-click on the table to get "Table Properties" when recording. Also, using the toolbar to get to the properties does not show the same popup as Outlook (and there is not macro recording in Outlook). The Word version does not have the "Same as the whole table" property.

Answer (score 0):

My bad,

Turns out that setting the padding *is* the way to turn off this property. The problem was actually in the `InchesToPoints` call that I copied and pasted from when I macro recording in MS Word.

**However** `InchesToPoints` is/was not an available method and that issue was hidden by the first line of my code:

```
On Error Goto Catch
```

(Shoot me now!)

So, `InchesToPoints` failed, which means the padding was NOT actually getting set. I made my own `InchesToPoints` method:

```
Public Function InchesToPoints(ByVal dInches As Double) As Double
    Const INCHES_TO_POINTS = 72#
    InchesToPoints = dInches * INCHES_TO_POINTS
End Function
```

And now it all works just fine.

**The actual correct answer** to this question **is setting the table padding** (E.g., `.TopPadding = 7.2` **will turn off the "Same as the whole table" property.**

Have a nice day.